# Using Inner Actions in Enterprise Architect V11

Tags: triggers, uml, state-machine, enterprise-architect

I am new here and would be grateful If anybody helps me. recently I have been working on state machine diagrams and UML language in general. I have been using Enterprise Architect (EA) V11 for drawing some state machine diagrams like drawing states, triggers, guards and events. It is known that there are two types of triggers 1. transition triggers that cause a transition from a state to another 2. inner triggers that doesn't cause a transition. EA supports only three types of inner triggers ( Entry, Exit, Do ) because of this I can't put in my own inner triggers as an example if enter button is pressed turn on a device. Another thing that I can't write commands that are going to be executed inside the state.
So I have two questions 1. How to name my own inner triggers? 2. how to write commands inside a state?

Any help please...

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you phrase your question as a question.  When I first read this, it didn't seem to be asking anything.

Comment: The questions seem clear. However, you should cross-post this on Sparx' forum too.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but **(1)** EA seems to support hierarchical state machines as shown in chapter "Compound states" in http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_statediagram.html. **(2)** You may be lucky in finding out how to code the state machines by inspecting the downloadable model used in the state machine simulation webinar at http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/demos/simulation_prototyping/simulation-and-prototyping.html

Comment: It really does support hierarchical state machines which helps, according to my knowledge, add states inside a state but how could this help in creating my own inner triggers? I have had a look at the simulation_prototyping example and many other examples. It seems that there are no inner triggers except for Entry, Exit and Do. There must be a way to overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. To create an inner trigger for a state, a self transition will do the trick. Create a transition connector issuing from and terminating in the state element and then modify its properties to be of kind internal. Then commands can be added by editing the Effect textbox.